# YML Date formatting according to user profile settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each user of our application can have different format for Date. 
I can use something like this `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"` in the application controller for changing by default date formatting.

But i want to change date formats in the en.yml to:

```
 date:
        formats:
          default: "%Y/%m/%d"
          short: "%b %d"
          long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

How can i change default, short and long date formates in yml file on the fly as we can use      `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"`.

Note: in view i use `<%= l Time.now.to_date, :format=>:short%>`

Thanks.

Comment: As I understand, you want to show date to each user in format he selected?

Comment: He will not select but we will get it from his profile settings as in DB.

Comment: Then you can use `strftime("format")` method: example `Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: But i want to use <%= l Time.now.to_date, :format=>:short%> and it will get format from en.yml. I want to get date format according to user profile settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in application controller only with different data format.
write in application controller.
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:data_format => "%d-%B-%Y")
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:data_format_month => "%m-%d-%Y")

and in view or helper call data_format or data_format_month.
example
 created_on.to_s(:data_format) for displaying D-B-Y format
 update_on.to_s(:data_format_month ) for displaying M-D-Y format

Comment: Thanks, It works fine but i want to use <%= l Time.now.to_date, :format=>:short%> in views which will get date format from en.yml file.